# Redirect user to wordpress category based on user-agent

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I was trying to make this with nginx and also with php header redirect in wordpress index.php but I always find myself in an infinite loop.

I just want to redirect iphone user to /category/iphone/ or android user to /category/android/ of my wordpress page.

Is this possible?

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
Maybe  I was not totally clear. I only want to redirect a user if he comes to INDEX/MAIN page. He can still browse other categories without redirecting him to iphone/android category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This if statment will allow you to to detect iOS and mobile device visitors using one of the following:

```
if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'ipad') ) {
        $device = "ipad";
    } else if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iphone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iphone') ) {
        $device = "iphone";
    } else if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'blackberry') ) {
        $device = "blackberry";
    } else if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'android') ) {
        $device = "android";
    }

    if( $device ) {
        return $device; 
    } return false; {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Even you can use .htaccess file like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Android.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoururl.com [R=301]
```

For in your functions.php file:

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'device_redirect' );

    function device_redirect(){
      if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
        if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iphone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iphone') ) {
                wp_redirect( "http://www.example.com/iphone", 301 );
        } else if( stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'android') ) {
               wp_redirect( "http://www.example.com/andriod", 301 );
        }
     }
   }
```

In case you use a static homepage or blog page you have to change the if.
For example

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
// Default homepage
}

if ( is_front_page()){
//Static homepage
} 

if ( is_home()){
//Blog page
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know how to detect devices with php or nginx, I just don't know how to redirect them to a category in wordpress environment, because wordpress runs all files through index.php.

Comment: if you put the last piece I added in the functions.php of your template then it should work.

Comment: I have added your suggestion, but if I refresh this category now I get infinite loop. And I can not browse any other categories because it always redirects me to iphone category. I only want main page redirected. Thank you!

Comment: I have added a if so I guess it will work now, I can't test it right now